# "Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported" I already added it as the documentation says

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, android-12

My application is in react native, it is an uber driver type.
I use location in the background.
notifications.
Information of the version of the app.
Camera.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMSLX.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kodn.png)

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqFiq.png)

[android/build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceo5p.png)

I also already made the changes with "./gradlew clean" but nothing shows me an error in the PlayStore as if I had not added anything to the AndroidManifest.xml

[Error PlayStore upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PGO8.png)

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of configuration files or code. Text should be posted as text so that is can be read easily and searched.